# Inconistent- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input - error in page with google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page with a google map that uses the google maps javascript api and directions api. when I load this, I get the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

very irregularly. It comes sometimes, but sometimes it does not. When tis eror is there, the directions api won't load, but other elements work. I understand that this might be a issue in the function which loads the directions, which is given below, but if so , why is it giving an error at random page loads only? why not everytime?

```
    function get_directions(cl_start, cl_end, waypts_json) {
        //alert("called");
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay1 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            suppressMarkers: true
        });
        //directionsDisplay1.suppressMarkers = true;
        directionsDisplay1.setMap(map);
        directionsService.route({
            origin: cl_start,
            destination: cl_end,
            waypoints: waypts_json,
            //optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay1.setDirections(response);
                var route = response.routes[0];

                //alert(status);
                // For each route, display summary information.
                for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                    var routeSegment = i + 1;
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Directions for part: ' + routeSegment +
                        ' of journey</b><br>';
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
                }
            } else if (status == "NOT_FOUND") {
                alert("called - not found");
                return false;
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use ajax and retrieve data and set them to the html?

Comment: yes, there are such instances, but all retrieved data is in the same format, so why does the error come irregularly?

Comment: Use the chrome debugger to find where exactly the error is coming from